# How to Geocode using web worker?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, web-worker

I am building an application which requires geocoding of contacts address. I want to do geocoding in background. For that I have tried webworker. But it is showing message "Script error.
Web worker script is:

```
importScripts('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js');
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "shivaji nagar pune"}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   postMessage(results[0].geometry.location);
  } else {
    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
  }
});
```

Comment: you can use the same api from a console application for exemple. It has not to be webbased.
So you check the address to geocode from your data base you passe them to the executable and it is done.

Comment: Is that your complete code?  Where do you create the `geocoder` object?

Comment: @geocodezip: No its my complete code code. created geocoder object above importScript().

Comment: @sabotero: can you please explain in detail?

Comment: I don't understand, how can it be your complete code if it doesn't include the definition of the geocoder object?

Comment: @Pratik you can for exemple use c# to get the address from your database. After that you itereate over the address and made a call to the api [this is te api reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding).

Comment: @geocodezip: Included geocoder but it still not worked for me

Comment: @sabotero I am building Phonegap Application so how can use C#. I want to geocode addresses in background with other script running parallelly.

Comment: aah I see, I thought when you said background was at the server level

Comment: Unless there is something different about the Phonegap environment to a usual browser, then I suspect doing this in a web worker is overcomplicating it. The calls to the geocode API are asynchronous, and any local processing I suspect is very minimal, and so would be fine to do in the standard UI Javascript environment.

Comment: @MichalCharemzaI Geocoding 100s of addresses consumes to much time. Can we do something which will which will geocode addresses in background? Will not affect other running scripts.

Comment: @Pratik How much Javascript time does it actually take?